# Lmer4 predict function is returning fitted values, not newdata values

Tags: r

I am running the following code:

```
results <- lmer(train$y ~ factor(train$x1) + (1|factor(train$x2)))
predicted <- predict(results, newdata=test)
```

However, `length(predicted)` is not equal to `nrow(test)`, but is instead equal to `nrow(train)`.

Even if I use `data=train` for `lmer`, I still have the same issue.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Looks like going this route fixed it.

`predicted <- predict(results, newdata=data.frame(y=test$y,x1=test$x1,x2=factor(test$x2)),allow.new.levels=TRUE)`

Comment: Try `?predictInterval`

Comment: Same issue. The column names in both my train and test data frame are exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `train$` during model fitting. Try:

```
results <- lmer(y ~ factor(x1) + (1|factor(x2)), data = train)
predicted <- predict(results, newdata=test)
```

Don't use any of the following:

```
results <- lmer(train$y ~ factor(train$x1) + (1|factor(train$x2)))
results <- lmer(train$y ~ factor(train$x1) + (1|factor(train$x2)), data = train)
```

This issue is not exclusive to `lmer`. For `lm`, `glm`, the same would happen.